# Inconsistent locationManager didupdatetolocation on Iphone

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

```
@implementation MyLocation


SYNTHESIZE_SINGLETON_FOR_CLASS(MyLocation);

@synthesize delegate, locationManager;

- (id) init 
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) 
    {       
        self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];

        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}


- (void) timeoutHandler:(NSTimer *)_timer
{

    timer = nil;

    [self update_location];
}

-(void) update_location
{
    hasLocation=NO;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 3.0
                                         target: self
                                       selector: @selector(timeoutHandler:)
                                       userInfo: nil
                                        repeats: NO
         ];
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"location ready");
    if(timer != nil) {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }
    hasLocation = YES;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"location_ready"                         object:nil]; 


    if (debug_switch)
        NSLog(@" Delegate function, Getting new location from locationManager from Mylocation.m");


    _coordinate = newLocation.coordinate;

    source_lat=_coordinate.latitude;
    source_lng=_coordinate.longitude;

    //TRACE(@"new location: %f %f", _coordinate.latitude, _coordinate.longitude);
    //[delegate locationUpdate:newLocation.coordinate];

}
```

The first time, I run the  update_location routine, the location manager quickly jump to callback routine of didupdatetolocation. No Problem

However, next time I call the update_location function again, the callback didupdatetolocation never entered.    Why such discrepancy? why the callback isn't entered?

Answer (score 2):

Your usage of LocationManager is incorrect. You only need to call startUpdatingLocation once, and the callback is invoked repeatedly whenever there is big enough change.

As of why with your observation, probably there was no significant change to invoke callback.

Comment: Ok, if I don't change my location would that callback be invoked again?

Comment: The callback will NOT be invoked until the location changes. Sometimes it does especially inside building, but that is due to fluctuation of GPS signal itself (so the callback will give you changed location).

Comment: And, the callback WILL be invoked right after the call of startUpdatingLocation even if you did not change location. I think in your original code, second and later startUpdatingLocation call is simply ignored. (That is my best guess, I haven't tried calling startUpdatingLocation multiple times.)

Answer (score 0):

Why create a timer that keeps calling CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation?

The CLLocationManager is typically used by setting yourself as the delegate. start it and then you get callbacks when the location changes.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

Here's a tutorial showing how to use it:

http://mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/